# Who should sign mail with Dkim?

Tags: exchange, smtp, dkim

I have an exchange server configured to use an external smarthost to send email.
If I want to complete my messages with DKIM signature should it set to my Exchage server o may I ask to my provider (smarthost) to sign them?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, DKIM signing is done by the sending server, so you should ask smarthost to sign the DKIM for your email. If you are using your own domain then you only need to update the DKIM record provided by your provider in your domain's DNS.